# Calculate distinct value and median and group by 2 values

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset that looks like this:

| client_id | Start_date_month | Provider |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11234 | 2020-01-01 | A |
| 1345 | 2020-01-01 | B |
| 1567 | 2020-01-01 | C |
| 1986 | 2020-02-01 | A |
| 15076 | 2020-02-01 | B |
| 174556 | 2020-02-01 | C |

What I want is to create a table that looks like this:

| Provider | Start_date_month | N_distinct | median |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2020-01-01 | 100 | 10 |
| B | 2020-01-01 | 70 | 6 |
| C | 2020-01-01 | 90 | 8 |

I have tried several methods to achieve it using the following 2 r scripts however, I am getting an error:

Library(dplyr)

```
starts <- intake_data %>% 
  filter(state == "ALS") %>%
  mutate(start_date_month=as.Date(start_date_month)) %>%
  summarize(group_by(provider, start_date_month),
            intakeA = n_distinct(client_id),
            medianA = median(client_id))
```

I have also tied this version:

```
starts <- intake_data %>% 
  filter(state == "ALS") %>%
  mutate(start_date_month=as.Date(start_date_month)) %>%
  group_by(provider, start_date_month) %>%
  summarize(intakeA = n_distinct(client_id),
            medianA = median(client_id))
```

but both version are not working. If someone could help me fix this code, that would be much appreciated

Comment: To read up on basic operations like this, have a look at https://r4ds.had.co.nz/transform.html#grouped-summaries-with-summarise

Answer (score 0):

Your code attempts suggest that you would like to group the data by both the provider and the month - in which case you do not end up with the output you describe (in which you silently drop one of the months).

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~client_id, ~Start_date_month, ~Provider,
      11234L,      "2020-01-01",       "A",
       1345L,      "2020-01-01",       "B",
       1567L,      "2020-01-01",       "C",
       1986L,      "2020-02-01",       "A",
      15076L,      "2020-02-01",       "B",
     174556L,      "2020-02-01",       "C"
  )

df |> 
  summarize(
    n_distinct = n_distinct(client_id),
    median = median(client_id),
    .by = c(Provider, Start_date_month)
  )
#> # A tibble: 6 × 4
#>   Provider Start_date_month n_distinct median
#>   <chr>    <chr>                 <int>  <int>
#> 1 A        2020-01-01                1  11234
#> 2 B        2020-01-01                1   1345
#> 3 C        2020-01-01                1   1567
#> 4 A        2020-02-01                1   1986
#> 5 B        2020-02-01                1  15076
#> 6 C        2020-02-01                1 174556
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: unfortunately it did not work, this is the error I receive - Error in `summarize()`:
ℹ In argument: `median = median(client_id)`.
Caused by error:
! `median` must return compatible vectors across groups.

Comment: Feel free to share your data that causes the problem. It works on the sample that you provided.

Comment: the output does not really look like the output I want though, for example, if you look at the median values, it only shows the client_id not the actual median number

Comment: That's because you only gave us one value per group.

Comment: unfortunately I am not able to share the dataset due to privacy reasons but this is what pretty much what the data looks like, I have data from January 1, 2020 to March 31 2022 for all 3 providers

Comment: What I meant is: the code doesn't have a flaw and you can just use it on your bigger dataset. If you ask R to compute the median of a single number x, it will return x. If you use it on more than just one number, you will get a "proper" median that you have in mind.

Comment: thank you, I have used the code above on the bigger dataset. I also used the code this way a well: summarize(
    n_distinct = n_distinct(client_id),
    median = median(n_distinct),
    .by = c(Provider, Start_date_month)
  )
However, the median value was just a replica of the n_distinct value (please let me know if a screenshot would be helpful). I am sure I did something wrong somewhere, but I am just not sure how to fix that

Comment: For each group, `n_distinct()` computes just one value. So with `median(n_distinct)` you are again computing the median of just one value, resulting in a "replica".

Comment: thank you, yes I figured doing these actions would not give me the result I want, is there a different way to get the median value to get the result I am looking for above?

Comment: Just compute it as in the code example in my original answer.

Comment: it gives me the median client_id though not the median clients per month that I am hoping to get as shown in my example above of what I want the data to look like